# HTTPS not working with custom domain in Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to configure a custom domain from namecheap to serve my cloudfront distribution. I did all steps i am aware of but the https is not working.

What i did:

1. created cname record for my domain in namecheap: `www -> d12312***.cloudfront.net`
2. created and validated amazon certificate from acm (it shows "issued" for `www.mysite.info`)
3. Edited my cloudfront distribution, included the domain `www.mysite.info` to the alternate domains section, selected "custom ssl" and selected the certificate i created from step 2.

Now my domain `www.mysite.info/test.jpg` does show the image hosted from my cloudfront, but the https is not working, showing "not secure", what's wrong ?

Please, I don't want to use route 53.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it worked after a while.
Though i struggled with the certificate manager dns verfication.
Amazon asks you to put a cname record like:

Name: _220a646ed9c024bb4e8a234d7224ae.www.mysite.com.
Type: CNAME
Value: _d5983967e8as12f80ae85685bb5ce7.hsdfuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws.

If you put/update the cname records as shown, it won't work, instead, remove the domain name from the name:

_220a646ed9c024bb4e8a234d7224ae.www

and keep the value as it is.

wait 10mins

Hit "continue" in amazon certifcate manager. voila! it shows certificate issued.